# static HTML site on Azure; 500.19 error; configuration section 'customerrors' cannot be read be read...missing a section declaration

Tags: azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I have inherited the occasional duties for updating my agency website. The website is a very basic, static HTML site that runs on Azure. Only gets updated with new PDF documents. A few weeks ago I got notified by some security people wanting the website to NOT display a yellow screen of death and instead only show a generic 500 status page. The yellow screen of death says that the web.config file can be modified to do this. OK, fine by me.

After looking it appears I don't have a web.config file so I created one but when I copy it via FTP to my Azure account it immediately kills the website. After looking in the error logs in Azure I see that there is a "500.19 error; configuration section 'customerrors' cannot be read be read...missing a section declaration".

Here is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<customerrors mode="off" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas on what is going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To handle 500 errors, aka Yellow Screens of Death, the following is added to the web.config, again shown as a config transformation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="500.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="500.aspx" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The 500.aspx page added to the site root contains the following markup at the top of the file:

```
<% 
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
 %>
```

**Note**: This is not ideal for a multi-site environment where the 500 page should be site-specific. To account for this, add logic to the 500.aspx page to transfer requests appropriately given the hostName requested.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/221/how-do-you-setup-a-404-and-500-error-page-for-missing-files-and-media-items).